# Custom SessionState Provider and Web Farm

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

I am working to expand our web application to work on a web farm.  I have written a custom session state provider.  All the pieces seem to work by themselves but together the site will eventually stop responding until I clear the session cookie and then it will suddenly all work again.

When I use the custom provider with a single web server everything works great.

When I use the farm with both web servers pointed to the same SessionStateService I am able to bounce between them and stay logged in, etc as expected.

Once I try to use the farm against with the custom provider it will work as expected for 3-5 page requests but eventually it just stops responding and the browser is stuck Waiting for page...

I have set the machine keys on both machines (confirmed by the session state service working) Althought this is only valid for view state I believe.

So is there some other settings or something out there that I am missing?  That is my only guess at this point other than an issue with locking that is some how only presenting itself when on the farm.  Two days of fighting with this has left me with no answers...

Comment: What does your custom session state provider do differently from the built-in session state service?  (i.e. Why do you need a custom one?)  Are you running the custom provider on each machine in the farm, or are you running one centrally, or are you running a separate cluster or farm of session state providers?  More generally, what can you tell us about your overall architecture?

Comment: I have written a provider to connect to cassandra.  I needed to be able to have a 100% distributed session that was on all nodes.  Each web machine will have its own local node as part of the cassandra cluster so any down time of a server will result in no down time for any users.  Running a single web server against the cassandra cluster works fine, even both web servers at the same time using local ip by themselves is fine.  Once I allow it to round robin it eventually go haywire.  Only thing I change is the session state xml node to the single session state service and it all works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tweaks to the locking in GetItemExclusive it seems to be working ok now.